# Unable to edit OHS Configuration Files in Enterprise Manager

Tags: oracle, weblogic11g

So I got this issue in Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g. I've installed it successfully and everything seems fine - all green! 
BUT when I try to edit settings with the OHS eg right click performance directives I get the following error

```
Failed to invoke operation load on MBean 
oracle.as.management.mbeans.register:type=component,name=ohs1,instance=asinst_1,Location=AdminServer Load failed with IOException
```

Anyone got this before and know how to fix this?

[image: Go to following link to see screenshot;]

Regards,

V

Comment: Add some screenshots, man, it will be easier to find out what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Give me some rep man! I need 10 to be able to post images.....

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to fix this issue. There is a specific issue with Java 7 and Oracle Fusion Middleware 11.1.1.6 and 11.1.2.0/11.1.2.1.

If this is the setup you are using please read on. If not continue with caution as the "Load failed and IOException" error message is very generic and you may have another issue.

This particular issue is because of an invalid SSL handshake. JDK 1.7 and $INSTANCE_HOME/config/OHS//admin.conf do not have the same SSL protocols defined.

To resolved this open the admin.conf file and change the line

```
SSLProtocol nzos_Verison_3_0
to
SSLProtocol nzos_Version_1_0 nzos_Version_3_0
```

Once you've done this save the file and restart the ohs component. Once back up this issue should be resolved and you can edit the config of ohs through the Enterprise Manager.

Regards,

V

Comment: There is hardly any reference to this issue elsewhere so please upvote this so it can be easily found. There is also oracle doc id 1463846.1 which details the above.