# Error on clicking advanced server configuration in weblogic

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, weblogic, java-7, weblogic11g

I am getting error on click advanced server configuration on weblogic em.

The error is:

> Failed to invoke operation load on MBean oracle.as.management.mbeans.register:type=component,name=ohs1,instance=fmfr,Location=AdminServer
>   Parsing error while loading MBeans

I tried [Unable to edit OHS Configuration Files in Enterprise Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241111/unable-to-edit-ohs-configuration-files-in-enterprise-manager)

it worked for the first time, and now again error is coming.

Comment: please, provide some code

Comment: there is no code, i am configuring weblogic em from browser.....

Comment: @GAURAVGKAR Might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241111/unable-to-edit-ohs-configuration-files-in-enterprise-manager